# Computing the Heyting operation on the frame of nuclei

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory, lattice-theory, locales, frames-and-locales

(The following definitions are meant to be standard and are reproduced for completeness of the question.)  A **frame** is a partially ordered set in which every finite subset has a greatest lower bound (“meet”, denoted $x_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n$, or $\top$ for the empty meet) and every subset has a least upper bound (“join”, denoted $\bigvee\{x_i : i\in I\}$), and such that the latter distributes over the former, which amounts to demanding $z \wedge \bigvee \{x_i : i \in I\} = \bigvee\{(z\wedge x_i) : i \in I\}$ (in fact, arbitrary meets exist in a frame, but they generally fail to distribute over joins).  (An important source of examples of frames are the lattice of open sets on a topological space, in which case finite meets and arbitrary joins are simply finite intersections and arbitrary unions.)  The **Heyting operation** on a frame $L$, denoted $\Rightarrow$, is defined as $(x\Rightarrow z) := \bigvee\{y : x\wedge y \leq z\}$ (this sup is, in fact, a max).  A **nucleus** on a frame $L$ is a map $j\colon L\to L$ such that ① $j(x\wedge y) = j(x)\wedge j(y)$ (from which it follows that $j$ is order-preserving), ② $x \leq j(x)$, and ③ $j(j(x)) = j(x)$ (these three conditions are understood universally quantified over free variables in $L$).  The set of nuclei on $L$, with the pointwise order (viꝫ., $j_1\leq j_2$ when $j_1(x)\leq j_2(x)$ for all $x\in L$) is itself a frame, denoted $N(L)$; its top element is $x \mapsto \top_L$ and bottom $x \mapsto x$.  Meet of nuclei can be defined pointwise: $(j_1\wedge j_2)(x) = j_1(x) \wedge j_2(x)$ (in fact, the same holds for arbitrary meets).  Joins of nuclei, however, are more difficult to compute in general, although it is true that the fixset $L_j := \operatorname{im} j = \{x\in L : j(x)=x\}$ of $j := \bigvee\{j_i : i\in I\}$ is $\bigcap_{i\in I} L_{j_i}$ (so $j(x)$ can be expressed as the smallest element $\geq x$ of $L$ which is fixed by every $j_i$).  See [Escardó, “Joins in the Frame of Nuclei” (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1023555514029) for details and references about nuclei in general and how to compute their join.

My question concerns the computation of the Heyting operation in the frame $N(L)$ of nuclei over a frame $L$.  So $j_1\Rightarrow j_2$ is defined as the largest nucleus $k$ such that $j_1(x) \wedge k(x) \leq j_2(x)$ for all $x$ (in particular, we have $(j_1\Rightarrow j_2)(x) \leq (j_1(x) \Rightarrow j_2(x))$).  But this is not an equality in general.

To provide at least one interesting example of this, for an arbitrary element $a\in L$ we two naturally occurring nuclei, $j_a\colon x\mapsto a\vee x$ (the “complementary closed sublocale” nucleus associated to $a$) and $j^a\colon x\mapsto (a\Rightarrow x)$.  They turn out to be complementary in $N(L)$ (see, e.g., Fourman & Scott, “Sheaves in Logic”, p. 302–401 in Fourman, Mulvey & Scott, *Applications of Sheaves (Durham 1977)*, Springer LNM **753** (1979), §2.18), in the sense that $j_a \vee j^a = \top_{N(L)}$ and $j_a \wedge j^a = \bot_{N(L)}$; in particular, we have $j^a = (j_a \Rightarrow \bot_{N(L)})$, which is unsurprising, but also $j_a = (j^a \Rightarrow \bot_{N(L)})$, which is more surprising as the inequality $a\vee x \leq ((a\Rightarrow x) \Rightarrow x)$ is generally not an equality (the RHS here is not a nucleus in $x$, although it *is* a nucleus in $a$ which caused me some level of confusion).

**Question:** How can we compute the value $(j_1\Rightarrow j_2)(x)$ of the Heyting operation for $j_1,j_2 \in N(L)$ two nuclei (and $x\in L$)?  Or how can we, at least, say something beyond the inequality $(j_1\Rightarrow j_2)(x) \leq (j_1(x) \Rightarrow j_2(x))$ remarked above?  Pretty much anything that can be said about $(j_1\Rightarrow j_2)(x)$ interests me, including the special cases $j_2 = \bot_{N(L)}$, and/or when $L$ is the lattice of open sets on a topological space $X$ and $j_1,j_2$ are defined by reflecting to open subsets of subspaces $E_1,E_2 \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, every nucleus is the join of those of the form $j^x\land j_y$.
Namely,
$$
j=\bigvee_xj^x\land j_{jx}
$$
Hm, this is too confusing. Let me change notation and write: $u_a$ instead of $j^a$; $v_a$ instead of $j_a$. Thus,
$$
j=\bigvee_xu_x\land v_{jx}.
$$

It then follows
$$
j_1\Rightarrow j_2=\bigwedge_x[(u_x\land v_{j_1x})\Rightarrow j_2].
$$
Next, since $u_x$ and $v_x$ are complements of each other, $u_x\Rightarrow j=v_x\lor j$ and $v_x\Rightarrow j=u_x\lor j$. Thus $[u_x\Rightarrow j]a=j(a\lor x)$ and $[v_x\Rightarrow j]a=x\Rightarrow ja$ for every $a$, $x$ and every nucleus $j$.

To show that $j(x\lor-)$ is a nucleus,
$$
j(x\lor j(x\lor a))=jj(x\lor a)=j(x\lor a)
$$
since $x\leqslant jx\leqslant j(x\lor a)$.

And, to show that $x\Rightarrow j-$ is a nucleus,
$$
x\Rightarrow j(x\Rightarrow ja)=x\Rightarrow(x\Rightarrow ja)=x\Rightarrow ja
$$
since $L_j$ is an exponential ideal, i. e. $b\in L_j$ implies $x\Rightarrow b\in L_j$ for any $x$.

This gives
$$
[j_1\Rightarrow j_2]a=\bigwedge_x j_1x\Rightarrow j_2(a\lor x),
$$
which can be also replaced by
$$
\tag{*}
[j_1\Rightarrow j_2]a=\bigwedge_{x\geqslant a}j_1x\Rightarrow j_2x,
$$
as well as
$$
[j_1\Rightarrow j_2]a=\bigwedge_x(a\Rightarrow x)\Rightarrow(j_1x\Rightarrow j_2x).
$$

One can also use that every nucleus is a meet of nuclei of the form $w_x$, where $w_x(a)=(a\Rightarrow x)\Rightarrow x$. Namely,
$$
j=\bigwedge_{x\in L_j}w_x.
$$
Using this, we can further replace $(*)$ with
$$
[j_1\Rightarrow j_2]a=\bigwedge_{x\geqslant a,y\in L_{j_2}}j_1x\Rightarrow((a\Rightarrow y)\Rightarrow y)$$
or as well with
$$
[j_1\Rightarrow j_2]a=\bigwedge_{x\geqslant a,y\in L}j_1x\Rightarrow((a\Rightarrow j_2y)\Rightarrow j_2y).$$

The version $(*)$ is the most concise but sometimes other versions might be more useful.

For references - all this must be in the book by Picado and Pultr, for example.

Comment: I have been unable to find this in the book “Frames and Locales” by Picado & Pultr: they mention that every nucleus is a join of $u_a\wedge v_b$ (though they don't even seem to mention the more precise form $j = \bigvee_x u_x\wedge v_{j(x)}$ which you point out), but they don't seem to discuss computing the Heyting operation on nuclei, despite a lengthy discussion of the corresponding (“co-Heyting”, or “pseudodifference”) operation on sublocales in §VI.4.5ss. Maybe I missed this. Anyway, your answer is entirely satisfactory.

Comment: (For full completeness, I would just like to add the clarification, because you used this implicitly, that $y\mapsto j(x\vee y)$ and $y\mapsto (x\Rightarrow j(y))$ are nuclei — not merely prenuclei — whenever $j$ is a nucleus and $x\in L$. This is not hard to check, and explains why $v_x \vee j$ and $u_x \vee j$ are given by the formulæ in question.)

Comment: Added that. As for the co-Heyting structure on sublocales - the lattice of sublocales is opposite of the lattice of nuclei. I did not remember whether they have the direct version or not. Where I have seen all this (and much more) for sure is Todd Wilson's thesis. It is on [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/35295449_The_assembly_tower_and_some_categorical_and_algebraic_aspects_of_frame_theory), for example.

Comment: For completeness of references, (*) is theorem 23.4(2) in chapter 6 in Todd Wilson's thesis (page 95). The proof there is a bit less self-contained than that in the answer above.